# Thunderbird integration with Salesforce

Tags: integration, appexchange, app, installedpackage

Anyone knows any app or plugin that is integrated with Thunderbird in Salesforce?

I have already checked [ThunderbirdMailConnector](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001skbaEAA), and besides the fact that the provider does not have a website(so it's not that reliable), and there is no documentation, I have installed it in a Sandbox Org, and still cannot find how to make it work.

Thank you in advance guys.
Endrit.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written an open source connector from Thunderbird to Salesforce.

It synchronises an addressbook of up to 1000 contacts and leads; it automatically archives email (if configured to do so) from multiple Thunderbird mail accounts into Salesforce - and it allows the creation in Salesforce of contact/lead record from the information in an email (first name/last name/email address).

The page on Thunderbird Add-Ons is here: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/grapevine/